# No option to copy artifacts download URL in new Azure DevOps Builds

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How can I copy artifacts download URL in new Azure Devops Builds?

Comment: That would be a relatively easy extension to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no option to directly copy the download url of artifacts. From the page, we can only download it by clicking the download button.

To solve this issue, we need to press `F12` in the browser then select `Network` to capture the download url .

[image]

Directly using the api captured in the above image, I can successfully download the artifact.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to construct your own link with format:

`https://devops.azure.com/{org_name}/{team_project_name}/_apis/build/builds/{build_id}/artifacts?artifactName={artifact_name}&api-version=5.1&%24format=zip`

1. `{org_name}` - name of your azure devops account
2. `{team_project_name}` - name of team project where your build runs
3. `{build_id}` - id of your build that contains your files to download. You can find it in the link:

[image]

4. `{artifact_name}` - name of your artifact (by default `drop`). You van find it in the published artifacts:

[image]